# Easiest method to retrieve the content of BLOBs from a Sybase databse

Tags: database-recommendation, sybase, blob

I would like know the easiest way (no coding) to extract the content of the blobs of a database.

For example, I have a table which contains a column whose format is BLOB.
The result I would like to get is to extract the content of the BLOB into CSV files.

What is the most elegant method to do this?
Is there a Sybase function to perform this? Or an existing software?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

> For example, I have a table which contains a column whose format is BLOB. The result I would like to get is to extract the content of the BLOB into CSV files.
>
> What is the most elegant method to do this?

[BCP OUT](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1573/html/utilityguide/X14951.htm) will be your best choice.

- Make sure your database has BLOB data (Image and/or TEXT datatypes). Also, `select into` should be set to TRUE for the database.
- Check the MAX length of the BLOB data using `select max(datalength(column_name)) from table_name`. Alternatively, you can use [this](http://www.petersap.nl/SybaseWiki/index.php?title=Bulk_copy_out_of_text_and_image_data) utility to do the same thing programatically.
- Use the above max datalength as `-T` parameter in BCP OUT.

  > **-T text_or_image_size**
  > allows you to specify, in bytes, the maximum length of text or image data that Adaptive Server sends. The default is 32K. If a text or an image field is larger than the value of -T or the default, bcp does not send the overflow.

> Is there a Sybase function to perform this? Or an existing software?

SybaseASE does not have a native function. Also, I am not aware of an existing software *(there might be, but I did not have a need to use them for getting BLOB data out of my sybaseASE)*.